# How can print all the identifiers in a large c++ project?

Tags: c++

How can  print  all the identifiers in a large c++ project?

Comment: On which OS/platform?  For what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Doxygen](http://doxygen.org) is what you are looking for.